# MobaXterm apt-get permanently install packages

Tags: apt, mobaxterm

I am using MobaXterm 10.8 portable.

Whenever I install any package with

```
$ apt-get install nano
```

I can use the package for the whole MobaXterm session.
But these packages vanish when closing MobaXterm.

On the other hand, [plugins](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/plugins.html) are persistent.

**Is there any way to make `apt-get` packages also permanent?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is setting a specific *Settings -> General -> Persistent root (/) directory*, instead of the default *< Temp >*:

[image]