# MobaXterm Portable + Plugins + permanent apps

Tags: plugins, apt, mobaxterm

I am using MobaXterm *portable* (I don't know if this makes any difference here).

I want to have some plugins, and at the same time install other apps. I found that:

1. Placing plugins in the same directory where the executable is located worked.
2. Then adding apps with `apt-get install ...` made them volatile, so whenever I closed and reopened MobaXterm, I had to `apt-get install ...` again.
   To add permanently these apps one has to [change the *Persistent root* (slash) directory in the MXT settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51496829/2707864).
3. But then plugins are not read anymore, e.g. 

    `$ git`

    `bash: /bin/git.exe: No such file or directory`

   It doesn't help placing the plugins in either the *Persistent home* or *Persistent root* directories.

**How can I have these 3 simultaneously?**
MXT portable + Plugins + Persistent apps.